# Why is git not pulling?

Tags: git

I created a local branch like so

```
$ git branch group_contact_form
```

I committed some changes then sent the branch to remote like so:

```
$ git push origin group_contact_form
```

I can quite happily keep pushing commits and `$ git branch -a` displays my local and remote branch

```
 * group_contact_form
   master
   remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
   ...
   remotes/origin/group_contact_form
   ...
```

But, when I try to pull with `$ git pull`:

```
fatal: 'origin/group_contact_form' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

My `.git/config` is as follows:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = database1:/var/git/repo_name.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "group_contact_form"]
    remote = origin/group_contact_form
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `merge` setting in the section `branch "group_contact_form"` seems to be wrong. I think it should be

```
merge = refs/heads/group_contact_form
```

Additionally, `remote` should be

```
remote = origin
```

That's the setting I receive after executing `git push origin mybranch`.

Comment: If somebody wonders were to find those settings at all: `.git/config`

Answer (score 7):

You should execute:

```
git remote show origin
```

This will give you a list of which local branches are [tracking branches](http://book.git-scm.com/4_tracking_branches.html)

If your local branch is not tracking the remote, you can create a tracking branch with:

```
git checkout -b origin/group_contact_form
```

Then just rebase your local branch so you can update the changes

Comment: +1 `git remote show origin` is pretty useful. Hadn't come across that before.

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
git branch --set-upstream group_contact_form origin/group_contact_form
```